# How to send additonal data along with form data in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am sending attached `files/images` with `formData` to back end along with content of the mail and then inject them into nodemailer, I am using multer as a middleware if it helps

#### component.ts

```
  let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if(fileList.length > 0) {
         this.formData = new FormData();
        for(let i = 0 ; i < fileList.length; i++){
        let file: File = fileList[i];
        this.formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
          }
  }
```

#### service.ts(this works and I can fetch files from req.files in the node)

```
 sendData(formData){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/mail',formData)
  }
```

#### service.ts(doesn't work, need to do this)

```
sendEmail(formData,email){
    let data = { data : email , formData : formData}
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/mail',data)
  }
```

both `req.files` and `req.body.formData` comes undefined in this case, 
I tried appending the `formdata` to the header but I don't know the proper way to append/fetch or maybe it's not possible to.

Node.js Part

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination : (req,file, callback)=>{
        req.body.path = [];
        callback(null, './storage');
    },
    filename : (req, file ,callback)=>{
        let filename = Date.now() + '-' +file.originalname;
        req.body.path.push(filename);
        callback(null, filename);

    app.post('/mail',upload.any(),nodemailer);
```

nodemailer.js

```
module.exports = (req,res)={
  console.log(req.files);  X
//Code Irrelevant for this question
}
```

Comment: try `req.data.formData.files` or `req.formData.files`

Comment: @UsmanRana So should I keep the service same like case 2?

Comment: yes. it can be .

Comment: @UsmanRana Node throws err : Cannot read property 'files' and 'data' of undefined in both cases

Comment: can you post your `nodejs` code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For this you have to do it like this :**

```
sendEmail(formData,email){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    formData.append('email', email);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/mail',formData);
}
```

> Reason, you have to pass the form as multipart and you are trying to
>   send data as JSON , so it will not receive anything until you pass the
>   whole thing as above.

---

```
sendEmail(formData,email){
    let data = { data : email , formData : formData}
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/mail',data)
}
```

as you can see in your function you are sending the JSON.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly but i am getting attached files with req.files and  email data with req.body why so? when i used the same method formData.append on both?

Comment: @MayankSingh, Great , and  you can read my updated answer and you will get the idea.